# Knocking yourself out?

Tags: fire-pro-wrestling-world

In Fire Pro Wrestling World is it possible to have a character knock themselves out for a story line? If so how would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this has been available to do since Fire Pro Wrestling D for the Dreamcast. It happens when a player does a move that inflicts damage to him and under the right conditions when performing that move on another player you can possibly knock yourself out.